# Why does python use unconventional triple-quotation marks for comments?

Tags: python, coding-style, comments

Why didn't python just use the traditional style of comments like C/C++/Java uses:

```
/**
 * Comment lines 
 * More comment lines
 */

// line comments
// line comments
//
```

Is there a specific reason for this or is it just arbitrary?

Comment: What?  Python uses # comments, which are common practice in lots of languages.

Comment: I meant the multi-line comments which start with `"""` I believe...

Comment: I know `#` is used in other languages (I know bash uses it).

Comment: Those aren't comments, they're docstrings.

Comment: They aren't docstrings.  They're just commonly used for docstrings so the string is easier to read.

Comment: No, what he's looking at and calling comments are almost certainly docstrings.

Answer (score 106, accepted):

Python doesn't use triple quotation marks for comments. Comments use the hash (a.k.a. pound) character:

```
# this is a comment
```

The triple quote thing is a [doc string](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/), and, unlike a comment, is actually available as a real string to the program:

```
>>> def bla():
...     """Print the answer"""
...     print 42
...
>>> bla.__doc__
'Print the answer'
>>> help(bla)
Help on function bla in module __main__:

bla()
    Print the answer
```

It's not strictly required to use triple quotes, as long as it's a string. Using `"""` is just a convention (and has the advantage of being multiline).

Comment: "It's not strictly required to use triple quotes, as long as it's a string. Using """ is just a convention." Huh, neat. I had no idea about that!

Comment: OIC now...I should have done some more research myself before asking this question...thanks though!

Comment: Excellent answer. I'd complement that it is usual to use strings as quick and dirty multiline comments too, when you want to comment out some lines for debugging purposes.

Comment: Great example code, but this answer lacks one detail I was looking for, which @eli-collins mentions in his answer below: "bare strings which follow _immediately_ after a `def Foo()`, `class Foo()`, or the start of a module, are treated as string containing documentation for that object, and stored in the `__doc__` attribute of the object".

Comment: To clarify what @RemingtonSteed mentioned: the string literal is _only_ interpreted as a docstring when it is the first statement in "a module, function, class, or method definition" (python.org). So you can use it like a comment in all other circumstances, and it is _not_ accessible as a runtime object attribute.

Answer (score 54):

A number of the answers got many of the points, but don't give the complete view of how things work. To summarize...

`# comment` is how Python does actual comments (similar to bash, and some other languages). Python only has "to the end of the line" comments, it has no explicit multi-line comment wrapper (as opposed to javascript's `/* .. */`). Most Python IDEs let you select-and-comment a block at a time, this is how many people handle that situation.

Then there are normal single-line python strings: They can use `'` or `"` quotation marks (eg `'foo'` `"bar"`). The main limitation with these is that they don't wrap across multiple lines. That's what multiline-strings are for: These are strings surrounded by triple single or double quotes (`'''` or `"""`) and are terminated only when a matching unescaped terminator is found. They can go on for as many lines as needed, and include all intervening whitespace.

Either of these two string types define a completely normal string object. They can be assigned a variable name, have operators applied to them, etc. Once parsed, there are no differences between any of the formats. However, there are two special cases based on *where* the string is and how it's used...

First, if a string just written down, with no additional operations applied, and not assigned to a variable, what happens to it? When the code executes, the bare string is basically discarded. So people have found it convenient to comment out large bits of python code using multi-line strings (providing you escape any internal multi-line strings). This isn't that common, or semantically correct, but it *is* allowed.

The second use is that any such bare strings which follow *immediately* after a `def Foo()`, `class Foo()`, or the start of a module, are treated as string containing documentation for that object, and stored in the `__doc__` attribute of the object. This is the most common case where strings can seem like they are a "comment". The difference is that they *are* performing an active role as part of the parsed code, being stored in `__doc__`... and unlike a comment, they can be read at runtime.

Comment: _"can be stored in a variable"_ There are no accessible variables in Python in which a value can be put in and pulled out. There are only objects.

Comment: True that. The terminology was perhaps a little too informal, but I was trying to keep my answer from going on for too long. "can have a reference to itself stored under a named key in the local scope dictionary" is probably closer to the truth, but is rather wordy, and sadly I can't think of a satisfactory middle ground for referring to an operation such `a="foo"`

Comment: The instruction ``a = "century"`` is an assignement and the related process is a binding of a name and an object

Answer (score 25):

Triple-quotes aren't comments.  They're [string literals](http://docs.python.org/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals) that span multiple lines and include those line breaks in the resulting string.  This allows you to use

```
somestr = """This is a rather long string containing
several lines of text just as you would do in C.
    Note that whitespace at the beginning of the line is\
 significant."""
```

instead of

```
somestr = "This is a rather long string containing\n\
several lines of text just as you would do in C.\n\
    Note that whitespace at the beginning of the line is\
 significant."
```

Answer (score 5):

Most scripting languages use # as a comment marker so to skip automatically the shebang (#!) which specifies to the program loader the interpreter to run (like in #!/bin/bash). Alternatively, the interpreter could be instructed to automatically skip the first line, but it's way more convenient just to define # as comment marker and that's it, so it's skipped as a consequence.

Answer (score 4):

Guido - the creator of Python, actually weighs in on the topic here:
https://twitter.com/gvanrossum/status/112670605505077248?lang=en

In summary - for multiline comments, just use triple quotes. For academic purposes - yes it *technically* is a string, but it gets ignored because it is never used or assigned to a variable.