# What is the difference between multi-line comment and multi-line string in python?

Tags: python, syntax

I am still exploring python. Today I came across multi-line strings. If I do:

```
a = '''
some-text
'''
```

The content of variable a is `'\nsome-text\n'`. But this leaves me confused. I always thought that if you enclose something within three single quotes (`'''`), you are commenting it out. So the above statement would be equivalent to something like this in C++:

```
a = /*
some-text
*/
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Comments are well explained [here](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/tutor/2004-February/028432.html)

Comment: *I always thought that if you enclose something within three single quotes ('''), you are commenting it out.* Hmm, you're not. You're wrapping that something in a string. Strings, even docstrings, aren't technically comments (they're evaluated, comments aren't).

Comment: To answer your question, please see http://stackoverflow.com/a/7057488/622306

Comment: @GianlucaMancini So there no such thing as multi-line comments. And multi-line stings double up as docstrings. Both are compiled. But single line comments are not. Is that correct?

Comment: @daltonfury42 Correct. The Python source code is [full](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/base64.py#L142) of this usage.

Comment: @daltonfury42 you can use *any* string as docstring: `def f():\n"hello"\n    return 42` works fine and provides `"hello"` as `f.__doc__`.  What you are doing by using multiline strings as comments is exactly the same as using a number in random places: `do_something; 42; do_something_else'. Python evaluates the expression but since its value isn't saved anywhere it is useless; if you are using a literal it will be compiled out, except if used as a docstring.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Technically such multi-line-comments enclosed in triple quotes are not really comments but string literals.

The reason why you can still use them to comment stuff out is that a string literal itself does not represent any kind of operation. It gets parsed, but nothing is done with it and it does not get assigned to a variable name, so it gets ignored.

You could also place any other literal into your code. As long as it is not involved in any kind of operation or assignment, it gets basically ignored like a comment. It *is not* a comment though, just useless code if you want to name it that way.

Here's an example of code that does... well, nothing:

```
# This is a real comment.

"useless normal string"

"""useless triple-quoted
multi-line
string"""

[1, "two"]  # <-- useless list

42  # <-- useless number
```

Answer (score 2):

> I always thought that if you enclose something within three single quotes (''')

This is not the case, actually.  Enclosing something in triple quotes `'''string'''`, it creates a string expression which yields a string containing the characters within the quotes.  The difference between this and a single quoted string `'string'` is that the former can be on multiple lines.  People often use this to comment out multiple lines.

However, if you don't assign the string expression to a variable, then you'll get something a lot like a comment.

```
'''this is
a useless piece of python
text that does nothing for
your program'''
```

In python, wrapping your code with `'''` will encode it as a string, **effectively commenting it out** unless that code already contains a multi-line string literal `'''` anywhere. Then, the string will be terminated.

```
print('''hello!
How are you?''')

# this will not have the intended comment effect
'''
print('''hello!
How are you?''')
'''
```