# How do I add the ' symbol to a string

Tags: python-3.x

I had someone help with a prior question to turn hexadecimal to string, but I want the string to output surrounded with `'`
so it returns `'I0KB'` instead of just `I0KB`.

What I have:

```
with open('D:\new 4.txt', 'w') as f:
   f.write('if not (GetItemTypeId(GetSoldItem())==$49304B42) then\n')

def hex_match_to_string(m):
    return ''.join([chr(int(m.group(1)[i:i+2], 16)) for i in range(0, len(m.group(1)), 2)])
# ...
line = re.sub(r'\$((?:\w\w\w\w\w\w\w\w)+)', hex_match_to_string, line)
file_out.write(line)
```

output:

> if not (GetItemTypeId(GetSoldItem())==I0KB) then

but I want it to output

> if not (GetItemTypeId(GetSoldItem())=='I0KB') then

and using

```
def hex_match_to_string(m):
    return ''.join(',[chr(int(m.group(1)[i:i+2], 16)) for i in range(0, len(m.group(1)), 2)],')
```

...gives me a syntax error even though I read that `join(a,b,c)` is the way to combine strings.

Thanks in advance for the help, and sorry I am clueless for what should be an easy task.

Answer (score 0):

You can put a backslash character followed by a quote ( \" or \' ). This is called an escape sequence and Python will remove the backslash, and put just the quote in the string.

Answer (score 0):

You should not add the quotes to the *argument* passed to `join`, but wrap the *result* of the `join` with quotes:

```
return "'" + ''.join([chr(int(m.group(1)[i:i+2], 16)) for i in range(0, len(m.group(1)), 2)]) + "'"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's important to distinguish between enclosing a string between, *single*, *double*, or *triple* quotation marks. See [answers here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7057450/why-does-python-use-unconventional-triple-quotation-marks-for-comments) regarding the most common use of the third (the so-called doc-strings).

While most of the time you can use `"` and `'` interchangeably, you can use them together in order to escape the quotation:

```py
>>> print("''")
''
>>> print('"')
"
```

You can also use the double quotes three times to escape any double quotes in between:

```py
>>> print(""" " " "j""")
 " " "j
```

But I'd suggest against the last option, because it doesn't always work as expected, for example, `print(""""""")` will throw an error. (And of course, you could always use the `\` to escape *any* special character.)