# why python allows triple quotes both as multi-line comment as well as string literal

Tags: python, syntax, comments

I am new to python and question may sound silly but I wanted to clear it. While learning I came across code where python is allowing triple quotes(""") both as multi-line comment and also as string literal. So how does python knows if it is intended as comment or a string literal.

```
"""This
is treated
as comment
and ignored"""

a = """It is
treated as
string literal"""
print(a)
```

Output:-

```
It is
treated as
string literal
```

Comment: This has a pretty good explanation about why these are both strings and not comments: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7057450/why-does-python-use-unconventional-triple-quotation-marks-for-comments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essentially, if the triple quotation marks aren’t assigned to a variable or a doc string, python will ignore it. For example

```
""""This is a module-level docstring""""


def randomFunction():
   """This will be treated as a docstring,
   so if you were to run help(randomFunction) it 
   will display whatever is in here"""


   a = """This is actually assigned to a variable,
   and thus python will interpret it as such"""

   """This by itself is just an unassigned string variable """
```

The same happens with strings, which are inside two quotes.

Comment: This is true for all string literals isn't it? Triple quotes just give you multi-line strings.

Comment: Yes all triple quotes are multi-line strings, but the way python interprets then depends on its context. As outlined above.

Comment: My point is that you can replace the first example with `"This by,itself will be ignored"` or `['this', 'will', 'be', 'ignored']`. There's nothing special about triple quotes that makes them ignorable. Random expressions are evaluated and discarded if you don't do anything with them.

Comment: Yeah I agree. Hence the comment on his question referencing how it’s not actually a comment but rather, the code is ran but nothing is done with it.

Comment: @MarkMeyer thanks your comment makes it more clear. Actually it was mentioned on this site to use """ as alternative for multi line comments so got confused. https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/statement-indentation-comments